# Writing a txt file with first row's length >= 8K turns the file format from unix into mac

Tags: unix, format, file-format

I've experience something I don't understand, when writing a text file under Ubuntu (tested on Ubuntu 14.04 and 12.04 64-bit). The "strange" thing is that when the length of characters (denoted as `N`) in **the first row** exceeds `8192`, the file format changes from `unix` to `mac` after saving the file. See the following `Python` script for example (also tested using `C++`). When `N >= 8192`, the newline character `\n` will be printed as `^J` in the file (i.e. in `mac` file format). However, if `N < 8192`, the file will act normally, i.e. remains `unix` format.

```py
N = 8192
a = '1'*N
with open('test.txt', 'w') as f_out:
    f_out.write(a)
    f_out.write('\n')
```

Also, it seems only the first rows matters: As long as `N < 8192` in the first row, no matter how many characters some other row has, the file format will remain as `unix`. For instance:

```py
N = 100000
a = '1'*N
with open('test.txt', 'w') as f_out:
    f_out.write('0\n')
    f_out.write(a)
    f_out.write('\n')
```

May someone explain this behaviour?

Thanks in advance!

**Updates:** I use `vim` to open the file and check the file format.

Comment: How are you testing the file format?

Comment: It's quite likely an artefact of the `file` program not reading more than 8 KiB of the file, and then not seeing any newline, so assuming it is Mac instead, especially if the long line includes one or more `'\r'` characters.

Comment: @FrederickCheung, I used `vim` to check the file format.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, may you elaborate a bit more? May I know if there is some way to customize the reading size of the `file` program?

Comment: It's all a hypothesis, but `file` probably doesn't look at the entire file; it looks at the first few bytes — where 'few' might be as many as 8 KiB judging from what you're observing.  I'm a little surprised you aren't getting "ASCII with very long lines"; but I don't know whether that requires a newline or CRLF or CR in the data to determine that — I've not looked at the source.  If you need to increase the size of the lookahead, you'll need to get the source and tinker with it.  I've not looked at it, so it might be trivial or it might be extremely hard.

Comment: On an ancient RHEL 5, I created a file with 16 KiB and no newlines at all; I got the classification "`single-line: ASCII text, with very long lines, with no line terminators`", so I'm not confident of my diagnosis — one reason it is commentary and not answer.  Have you looked at your data with a hex dump or equivalent?  Are the CR characters in it?

Comment: I've not seen `vim` spontaneously change from `fileformat=unix` to `fileformat=mac` — I wasn't aware of, though I'm not surprised to hear of, the `fileformat=mac`.  I don't know that I have any help to offer.